# How to share data between apps in offline

Tags: ios8, sandbox, ios9

I would like to share some files and data between apps in offline.

till iOS 7 as far as I searched there is no way to do that locally except using iCloud or something like that.

After the arrival of iOS 8 and 9.

Its highly possible apple might have introduced something.

Anybody have any idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to use NFC or bluetooth.

Comment: Hi ANDREW you mistook the question actually ! I meant to share the data between apps not devices